# I am having trouble understanding some basic code

Tags: spring, rest, api

This code is giving me headache. Maybe this is a lame question. I have been using REST API for some time. But I have never used URI and unable to understand why we are using URI here. Why do we need to URI object into the response?

This method is using post mapping.

@PostMapping("/user")

```
    long gameId = gameService.createGame(gamePostDTO.getPlayerIds());

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromCurrentRequest()
        .buildAndExpand("1")
        .buildAndExpand(String.format("%d", gameId))
        .toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

Comment: Because when you create a resource, you should tell the client where it can access that resource. This isn't related to the code, it's basic REST API design.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge regarding this. But @PostMapping("/user") also represents the same thing?

Comment: No, that configures the route the request should be made to but not the Location header on the response.